# jQuery - Select previous DOM element matching a class, when the DOM element is not in the same tree

Tags: jquery, dom, css-selectors

I'm trying to use jQuery to access a DOM object that appears earlier in the code from the DOM object that I am starting with. This would ordinarily be easy with jQuery's traversal methods, like .parentsUntil. However, in this case the object I am trying to find is not a parent or sibling of the object I am starting from.

For example, imagine this hierarchy:

- table

  - tr

    - td A
    - td B
  - tr

    - td C

      - input D

Starting at input D is it possible to find the html() of td A when there could be any number of elements between A and D?

Thanks for your help, and I apologize if this is too vague, I'll rewrite the question if needed.

Comment: I assume A B C and D are not IDs, so you can't simply select A directly. Are they classes? Plain text content? Is the trouble that there could be multiple As? Multiple tables?

Comment: Correct, A B C and D are not IDs. The problem is that input D, could easily be input Z, and I am looking for the first occurrence of a class that came before it in the HTML. There may be no relationship in the DOM tree between input Z and td A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain what you're asking (see my comment above). So, assuming you want to find the html content of the `td` of class `A` that is closest to element `D` while also being "above" `D` in the DOM, you could try something like this:

```
$('input#D')      // somehow uniquely identify our starting point
  .closest('tr')  // up to the closest enclosing TR
  .prevAll()      // and then get its preceding siblings
  .has('td.B')    // reduce this set to only those containing a td.B
  .last()         // choose the last one (thus closest to 'D')
  .find('td.B')   // now work downward to td.B itself
  .html();        // and get the content
```

It's off the top of my head, so there's probably a more efficient way to do this (and it's untested), but maybe this gives you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks Ken! I think this will work just fine for this case. You rock!